# Overriding get logic in tastypie

Tags: python, tastypie

Basically, I would like to log each call for specific object, lets say I have an objectA and objectB, whenever objectA is requested I want to increase counter of objectA in database. I am thinking about overriding API which makes `GET` request in `tastypie` for this specific type of model, but I don't know which place I should change or is there any other way to do this which is more preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best place to put it is the `obj_get` resource method that is called to retrieve an object. Inside you should check if the object was retrieved by the original method and do the incrementation.
    from tastypie.exceptions import NotFound

```
def obj_get(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    try:
        obj = super(self, ResourceClass).obj_get(bundle, **kwargs)
        obj.counter_field += 1
        obj.save()
        return obj
    except NotFound:
        raise
```

The above code wasn't tested (please update it with a working example after checking) but it shows what has to be done.